# How to create own Custom Predicate to compare composite id in hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to create my own custome predicate to compare composite id's inside object. The need is to because i have to write specific date comparison logic on object inside object (composite id).  *I don't want to compare individual attributes.i want to use composite id because it comes from invoker* and I can't get result using Predicate.in and Predicate.equals

My Object structure is like below

```
Birth{id=BirthId{name='b3', dob=Wed Jan 01 10:53:20 IST 1902}, name='b3', dob=Wed Jan 01 10:53:20 IST 1902, description='MNP'}
```

and inside IMap it is stored like below

```
key   : BirthId{name='b3', dob=Wed Jan 01 10:53:20 IST 1902}

value : Birth{id=BirthId{name='b3', dob=Wed Jan 01 10:53:20 IST 1902}, name='b3', dob=Wed Jan 01 10:53:20 IST 1902, description='MNP'}
```

My Java Classes(Birth and Birthid) Structure is below

```
    public class Birth implements Serializable, Portable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private BirthId id;
        private String name;
        private Date dob;
        private String description;

        public BirthId getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(BirthId id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Date getDob() {
            return dob;
        }

        public void setDob(Date dob) {
            this.dob = dob;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return (new HashCodeBuilder()).append(this.id).append(this.name).append(this.dob).toHashCode();
        }

        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (other == this) {
                return true;
            } else if (!(other instanceof Birth)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Birth rhs = (Birth) other;
                return (new EqualsBuilder()).append(this.id, rhs.id).append(this.name, rhs.name).append(this.dob, rhs.dob).isEquals();
            }
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return "Birth{" + "id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + ", dob=" + dob + ", description='" + description + '\'' + '}';
        }

        public int getFactoryId() {
            return 1;
        }

        public int getClassId() {
            return 1;
        }

        public void writePortable(PortableWriter portableWriter) throws IOException {
            portableWriter.writePortable("idComposite", getId());
            portableWriter.writeUTF("id", getId().toString());
            portableWriter.writeUTF("name", getName());
            portableWriter.writeUTF("description", getDescription());
            Date date = getDob();
            portableWriter.writeLong("dob", ((date == null) ? -1 : date.getTime()));
        }

        public void readPortable(PortableReader portableReader) throws IOException {
            setId((BirthId) portableReader.readPortable("idComposite"));
            setName(portableReader.readUTF("name"));
            setDescription(portableReader.readUTF("description"));
            long date = portableReader.readLong("dob");
            setDob(((date == -1) ? null : new Date(date)));
        }

    }

public class BirthId implements Comparable<BirthId>, Serializable, Portable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private Date dob;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (new HashCodeBuilder()).append(this.name).append(this.dob).toHashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (!(other instanceof BirthId)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            BirthId rhs = (BirthId) other;
            return (new EqualsBuilder()).append(this.name, rhs.name).append(this.dob, rhs.dob).isEquals();
        }
    }

    public int compareTo(BirthId rhs) {
        return this == rhs ? 0 : (null == rhs ? -1 : (new CompareToBuilder()).append(this.name, rhs.name).append(this.dob, rhs.dob).toComparison());
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "BirthId{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", dob=" + dob + '}';
    }

    public int getFactoryId() {
        return 1;
    }

    public int getClassId() {
        return 2;
    }

    public void writePortable(PortableWriter portableWriter) throws IOException {
        portableWriter.writeUTF("name", getName());
        Date date = getDob();
        portableWriter.writeLong("dob", ((date == null) ? -1 : date.getTime()));
    }

    public void readPortable(PortableReader portableReader) throws IOException {
        setName(portableReader.readUTF("name"));
        long date = portableReader.readLong("dob");
        setDob(((date == -1) ? null : new Date(date)));
    }

    public static ClassDefinition getClassDefinition(int portableVersion) {
        ClassDefinitionBuilder result = new ClassDefinitionBuilder(1, 2, portableVersion);
        result.addUTFField("name");
        result.addLongField("dob");
        return result.build();
    }

}
```

I have created own custom Predicate to compare dates like below

```
public class DatePredicate extends AbstractPredicate<Comparable, BirthId> {

    Comparable[] values;
    private volatile Set<Comparable> convertedInValues;

    public DatePredicate() {
    }

    public DatePredicate(String attribute, Comparable... values) {
        if (values == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Array can't be null");
        } else {
            this.values = values;
        }
    }

    protected boolean applyForSingleAttributeValue(Map.Entry entry, Comparable attributeValue) {

        //My own date comparison logic
        return true;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return 99;
    }
}
```

Caller code is

```
Predicate p = new DatePredicate("id", new BirthId("12345",passSpecifiedDate()));
Result res = imap.values(p);
```

I am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ArrayDataSerializableFactory@5f007be3 is not be able to create an instance for id: 99 on factoryId: -32
```

I do not know the best way to create own custom predicate and hazelcast doc does not specify the also.

Could any please guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@oomph-fortuity, your `DatePredicate` extends `AbstractPredicate` which implements `IdentifiedDataSerializable` and used by built-in Hazelcast predicates. Built-in Predicate Serializable Factory try to deserialize your class & fails since it only knows how to serialize/deserialize built-in Predicates.

Instead, just implement `com.hazelcast.query.Predicate` interface:

```
class DatePredicate implements Predicate<BirthId, Birth> {

BirthId birthIdToCompare;

public DatePredicate() {
}

public DatePredicate(BirthId birthId) {
    this.birthIdToCompare = birthId;
}

@Override
public boolean apply(Map.Entry<BirthId, Birth> mapEntry) {
    BirthId key = mapEntry.getKey();
    ///your custom logic
    return true;
}
}
```

And call like this

```
Predicate p = new DatePredicate(new BirthId("12345",passSpecifiedDate()));
Result res = imap.values(p);
```

Let me know if that works.