# How to compare 2 instants with Hazelcast predicate?

Tags: java, hazelcast, predicate

I would like to create a query with Hazelcast predicate to compare 2 instant type dates. However when I compare 2 different instants with `lessEqual` or `greaterEqual`, I have a wrong result set. Is there any way to compare 2 instant type objects with Hazelcast predicates?

Comment: I added an answer to your question, if it satisfy the requirement please accept it as answer .

Comment: I think it is a partial answer, I believe that the solution is implementing the predicate interface in a separate class as in your example.

Comment: So if its the case approve it as answer and if you need any improvement feel free to ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess its all about comparing, Hazelcast native predicate serialization Factory try to deserialize your class and the failure came from it only knows how to serialize/deserialize native predicates which you can find and example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48248538/15758781), more over the equals() in predicate will check if two instances are identically same in the **heap** thus they must have same pointer on stack in running thread.